# C++ Qt write to unix socket

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, unix

I have a unix socket in /tmp/my_sock

How can I connect to it and write data? Is there a Qt way to do it?

Comment: Regarding a Qt way to do it, I assume you have looked at - [Qt Signals and Slots](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/signalsandslots.html) ?

Comment: The Qt way is to not use a unix socket. The C++ way is to use the C way.

Comment: @arunkumar How do signals and slots help in this scenario? One of us is confused.

Answer (score 8):

Qt supports unix domain sockets natively through `QLocalSocket` and `QLocalServer`.

The name you have to pass as first parameter to `QLocalSocket::connectToServer` is the socket path: `"/tmp/my_sock"`.

Answer (score 1):

**As of 2011**, Qt doesn't have any support for sockets at all, since Qt's moto is *cross-platforming*.

If you want to use sockets in your Qt program, you should implement socket communication via standard Linux functions, [socket()](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/2/socket.htm), [connect()](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/2/connect.htm), etc, or implement your own class based on [QAbstractSocket](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qabstractsocket.html).

Comment: I''m not going to nitpick to the point of a downvote, but you're wrong. I think what you meant to say was that Qt does not easily support _native_ sockets through the API.

Comment: @San Jacinto: Correct. And, there is no need to nitpick, I downvote only absurd answers which is not your case.